# missing refs/heads for branches after pushing to new remote

Tags: git, git-push

I am migrating repositories from gitolite to bitbucket (on-prem) using the following steps:

1) Clone existing repository from gitolite:

```
git clone git@gitolite.mydomain.com:/hello-world
```

2) Add new remote for bitbucket:

```
git remote add origin-bb ssh://git@bitbucket.mydomain.com:7999/test/hello-world.git
```

3) Push all branches to new bitbucket origin:

```
git push origin-bb --all
```

4) Push all tags to new bitbucket origin

```
git push origin-bb --tags
```

The pushes complete successfully with no errors.  However, when I compare the refs between the two origins using `git ls-remote -h origin` and `git ls-remote -h origin-bb` the original remote has refs/heads listed for all branches, while the new remote only has refs/heads/master listed:

```
git ls-remote -h origin-bb

0079dbeb885c9d88ac200d533930e2e72feb3627        refs/heads/master

git ls-remote -h origin

3215eca2b034d4ee8406bca9b648808fb489c110        refs/heads/hot_fixes
5cfec9cab26d2805064b076d701e53e12ff59c51        refs/heads/develop
61e7efadb6c071f25007dda55ce8c9b73802e1c3        refs/heads/experiment
0079dbeb885c9d88ac200d533930e2e72feb3627        refs/heads/master
```

Is this the expected behavior or do I need an additional option when pushing to the new remote to ensure all refs are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `git ls-remote origin` not with `git ls-remote origin-bb` but with `git ls-remote .` i.e. with the current repo. I'm sure you'll see you only have 1 branch `master` and that is what `git push --all` pushed.

First you need to fetch all branches to the local repo as `git clone` clones only 1 branch:

```
git fetch origin hot_fixes:hot_fixes
git fetch origin experiment:experiment
```

And now repeat `git push --all origin-bb`.

Comment: fetching each branch worked like a charm! Thank-You.

Comment: Note that for fully-copying a repository from point A to point B through intermediate copy C, you can more simply use `git clone --mirror <url-of-A>` when copying to C, then `git push --mirror <url-of-B>` from the mirror clone made on C (then, generally at least, remove the mirror clone since it has outlived its usefulness—it's possible to convert it to a more normal bare clone referring to `B`, or even to a non-bare clone, but that's more work than removing and re-cloning :-) )